# Application not called when i click a link

Tags: android, download, android-manifest

I'm developing an android app and I would like to open my application when a link for file download on a certain website is clicked. I've read some guides for Android manifest file and this is the manifest I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.ada"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MyApp"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="message/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="multipart/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                      android:host="my.subdomain.com" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="message/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="multipart/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" /> 
                <data android:scheme="http"
                      android:host="my.subdomain.com" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The problem is that when I browse `my.subdomain.com/somefile.ext` (with https or http), a download starts without asking me if I want to open the link with my app.

What am I missing?

Comment: are you using a standard browser or a webview?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to define the `scheme` attribute (https://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)

Comment: It's already defined: `<data android:scheme="https" android:host="my.subdomain.com" />`